# ValueError: x and y must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a finite difference approximation to solve the Heat Equation, `u_t = k * u_{xx}`, in Python using NumPy.

Here is a copy of the code I am running:

```
    ## This program is to implement a Finite Difference method approximation
## to solve the Heat Equation, u_t = k * u_xx,
## in 1D w/out sources & on a finite interval 0 < x < L. The PDE
## is subject to B.C: u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0,
## and the I.C: u(x,0) = f(x).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters    
L = 1 # legnth of the rod
T = 10 # terminal time
N = 10 
M = 100
s = 0.25

# uniform mesh
x_init = 0
x_end = L
dx = float(x_end - x_init) / N

x = np.arange(x_init, x_end, dx)
x[0] = x_init

# time discretization
t_init = 0
t_end = T
dt = float(t_end - t_init) / M

t = np.arange(t_init, t_end, dt)
t[0] = t_init

# Boundary Conditions
for m in xrange(0, M):
    t[m] = m * dt

# Initial Conditions
for j in xrange(0, N):
    x[j] = j * dx

# definition of solution u(x,t) to u_t = k * u_xx
u = np.zeros((N, M+1)) # array to store values of the solution

# Finite Difference Scheme:
u[:,0] = x**2 #initial condition

for m in xrange(0, M):
    for j in xrange(1, N-1):
        if j == 1:
            u[j-1,m] = 0 # Boundary condition
        elif j == N-1:
            u[j+1,m] = 0
        else:
            u[j,m+1] = u[j,m] + s * ( u[j+1,m] - 
            2 * u[j,m] + u[j-1,m] )

print u, #t, x
plt.plot(u, t)
#plt.show()
```

I think my code is working properly and it is producing an output. I want to plot the output of the solution `u` versus `t` (my time vector). If I can plot the graph then I am able to check if my numerical approximation agrees with the expected phenomena for the Heat Equation. However, I am getting the error that "x and y must have same first dimension". How can I correct this issue?

An additional question: Am I better off attempting to make an animation with `matplotlib.animation` instead of using `matplotlib.plyplot` ???

Thanks so much for any and all help! It is very greatly appreciated!

Comment: With python problems, it is generally a good idea to show the complete stack trace.  Otherwise, people have to infer/guess which line of code and under what circumstances the error occurs.

Comment: The error only comes up when I run the line `plt.plot(u, t)`. If I remove that line then the code executes and prints the value for `u`.

Comment: Also the compiler produces this: `if x.shape[0]  != y.shape[0]: raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")`

Comment: My guess is that the shapes of `u` and `t` don't match.  Did you check those?

Comment: Yes I tried to make them match. When I defined the solution `u` to be an `NxM` array, I get an index error for the line containing `u[j,m+1] = u[j,m] + s * ( u[j+1,m] - 2 * u[j,m] + u[j-1,m] )` stating "index 100 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 100" ... if I define `u` to be a `(N+1)x(M+1)` array then for the line containing `u[:,0] = x**2` I get the ValueError: "could not broadcast input array from shape (10) into shape (11)". It is only when I define `u` to be an `Nx(M+1)` array that my code executes without error and prints a value for `u`. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had a "brain dump" and tried plotting `u` vs. `t` sort of forgetting that `u`, being the solution to the Heat Equation (`u_t = k * u_{xx}`), is defined as `u(x,t)` so it has values for time. I made the following correction to my code:

```
print u #t, x
plt.plot(u)
plt.show()
```

And now my programming is finally displaying an image. And here it is:

[image]
It is absolutely beautiful, isn't it?